# Get info by javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get specific column from second table by javascript and return data of it to my view but i'm not sure how it can be done.

## Logic

1. Products table has `price` column
2. Discount table has `product_id`, `min`, `max` and `amount` columns
3. I input number as quantity, if have product id in my discount table
   base on `min` and `max` return the `amount` as new price

## Code

so far this is my codes (I am aware that specially my controller method has identifying issue to find te right data)

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // if quantity is not selected (default 1)
    $('#newprice').empty();
    var quantity =  parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
    var shipingcost = parseFloat(quantity);
    var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
    var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        maximumFractionDigits:0, 
        minimumFractionDigits:0
    });
    $('#newprice').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');

    // if quantity is changed
    $('#quantity').on('change', function() {
      var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
      var qtyminmax = $(this).val();
      if(qtyminmax) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('admin/qtydisc') }}/'+encodeURI(qtyminmax),
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data) {
            $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
            var shipingcost = parseFloat(data)+parseFloat(quantity);
            var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
            var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                maximumFractionDigits:0, 
                minimumFractionDigits:0
            });
            $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');
          }
        });
      }else{
        //when quantity backs to default (1)
        $('#newprice').empty();
        var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
        var shipingcost = parseFloat(quantity);
        var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
        var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            maximumFractionDigits:0, 
            minimumFractionDigits:0
        });
        $('#newprice').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

`Route`

```
Route::get('qtydisc/{id}', 'ProductController@qtydisc');
```

`Controller`

```
public function qtydisc($id){
      return response()->json(QtyDiscount::where('min', '>=', $id)->orWhere('max', '<=', $id)->pluck('min'));
    }
```

## Question

1. What should I change in my controller method to get the right data?
2. What should I change in my JavaScript code? should I add `product
   ID` in my route as well or...?

## UPDATE

I'm trying some changes in my code but I can't get right `amount`

`controller`

```
public function qtydisc($id, $qty){
      $price = DB::table('qty_discounts')
              ->where('product_id', $id)
              ->where([
                  ['min', '>=', $qty],
                  ['max', '<=', $qty],
              ])
              // ->where('min', '>=', $qty)
              // ->where('max', '<=', $qty)
              ->select('amount')
              ->first();
      return response()->json($price);
    }
```

`route`

```
Route::get('qtydisc/{id}/{qty}', 'ProductController@qtydisc');
```

`javascript`

```
//as before...

$('#quantity').on('change', function() {
      var idofproduct = ["{{$product->id}}"]; //added
      var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
      var qtyminmax = $(this).val();
      if(qtyminmax) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('admin/qtydisc') }}/'+idofproduct+'/'+encodeURI(qtyminmax), //changed
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data) {
            $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
            var shipingcost = parseFloat(data)+parseFloat(quantity);
            var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
            var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                maximumFractionDigits:0, 
                minimumFractionDigits:0
            });
            $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');
          }
        });
      }else{
//rest of it as before
```

### Screenshot

[image: screenshotdb]

that's how my database look like and as results for quantity between `2` to `6` i get `7000` while i have to get `5000` from `2` to `5`.

From number `7` to `9` i get no results at all.

From number `10` to up all i get is `7000`

Any idea?

Comment: Is there any intentional reason you use an array for `idofproduct` (`var idofproduct = ["{{$product->id}}"];` ) when it looks like you need a scalar value? (`var idofproduct = "{{$product->id}}";`)

Comment: @alariva no it was in use in my other part of application so i just copy it from there can be as your suggestion as well, seems the issue was my database column. could you see my question in this comment please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585831/get-info-by-javascript-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment90214767_51624634

Comment: isn't `parseFloat(data)+parseFloat(quantity)` should be `parseFloat(data)*parseFloat(quantity)` ??

Comment: Show us your HTML structure please.

Comment: Why route URL is `qtydisc/{id}/{qty}` but ajax URL is `admin/qtydisc`?

Comment: @brlebtag bro, do you see `+idofproduct+'/'+encodeURI(qtyminmax)`? they pass `{id}` and `{qty}` and admin is prefix of my route group so my total url is `site.co/admin/qtydisc/2/45`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem comes from your eloquent statement, you should use the `>=` in both conditions with `OR` operator using the `orWhere` helper, so it should be like :

```
$price = QtyDiscounts::where('product_id', $id)
    ->where('min', '>=', $qty)
    ->orWhere('max', '>=', $qty)
    ->pluck('amount')
    ->first();
```

But you need really to take a look to your JS structure, I suggest to split your code to function for the DRY concept, first the event listener like :

```
$('body').off('input', '#quantity').on('input', '#quantity', function () {
    var qty = parseInt( $(this).val() );

    if(qty) {
        getAmount(qty);
    }else{
        getAmount(1);
    }
});
```

Then the helper functions to call :

```
function setValue(quantity, amount)
{
    var newPrice = $('#newprice');
    var totalPrice = $('#totalPriceInTotal');

    newPrice.empty();
    totalPrice.empty();

    var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        maximumFractionDigits:0,
        minimumFractionDigits:0
    });

    newPrice.val('Rp '+nf.format(amount)+'');
    totalPrice.val('Rp '+nf.format(parseFloat(amount)*parseFloat(quantity))+'');
};

function getAmount(quantity)
{
    var url = $('#qty_url').val();
    var productId = $('#product_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: url+'/'+productId+'/'+encodeURI(quantity),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(amount) {
            setValue(quantity, amount);
        }
    });
};
```

I guess you've a simple HTML structure, so it should work this way, why I suggest here if never using the php variable like `url` & `product_id` directly inside your JS code instead attach the values you want to hidden inputs and get the value of these input's using the JS :

```
<input type="hidden" id="qty_url" value="{{ url('admin/qtydisc') }}" />
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the opposite condition in the backend controller:

```
$price = DB::table('qty_discounts')
          ->where('product_id', $id)
          ->where('min', '<=', $qty)
          ->where('max', '>=', $qty)
          ->select('amount')
          ->first();
```

So for `$id` = 2 and `$qty` = 5 you will get

```
product id = 2  and `min` <= 5 and `max` >= 5
```

selecting the first row (`row_id` = 1)

Comment: with this i get amount till qty = 5 but when i try qty 6 it returns `{}` it seems not getting the exact rows in my table.

Comment: Try checking the raw query generated using `->toSql()` instead of `->first()` to see if there is any SQL problem or something wrong with the $qty parameter

Comment: result: `"select `amount` from `qty_discounts` where `product_id` = ? and `min` <= ? and `max` >= ?"` and `"select `amount` from `qty_discounts` where `product_id` = ? and `min` <= ? and `max` >= ?"`

Comment: Try using `->getBindings()` instead of `->toSql()` to show the replaced values in the query

Comment: i get this `["2","8","8"]` `2` is my product id `8` was my input as qty, other `8` i don't know what it is

Comment: I have thought not sure if it's correct or not, as you see in my screenshot i have 3 rows with same `product_id` maybe we should first make array (collection) of all rows with same product_id then check the values of `min` and `max`  what do you think?

Comment: It's better to do the filter inside the query instead of doing in the collection. The values are ok (one for each condition in `?`) Could you check in the database if min and max are integer fields, it seems like there is a problem with ranges.

Comment: they are `varchar` not `int`

Comment: ok, it seems that is working when i changed them to integer, but i do have 2 questions, `1` should i convert amount column to integer as well? `2` for integer what should i fill as Length/Values?

Comment: If your uantities will always be integers, change that column to integer. You dont need to fill-in the length field.

Comment: @mafortis you can use `int` (without length) if you plan to store integer values up to 2147483648, otherwise use `long`. For amounts with decimals it would be better using `float`, or `double` for better decimal precision. The length is not needed by default for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Stop mixing JavaScript with jQuery, instead of

```
var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
```

You could just do

```
var quantity = +$('#quantity').val();
```

And expect this to work even in old Internet Explorer

**Going further**

Routes

```
Route::get('/ajax/product/{product}/distcounts', 'AjaxController@productDiscounts);
```

Html

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" data-product_id="{{ $product->getKey() }}">
```

PHP

```
public function productDiscounts(Product $product, Request $request) {
    // $product is just a product you are interested in
    // $request->quantity containts passed amount

    $discounts = DiscountModel::product(     // Scope
        $product->getKey()
    )
    ->get()
    ->filter(function($element) use($request) {
        return ($element->min <= $request->quantity && $element->max >= $request->quantity);
    })
    ->values();

    return response->json(discounts);
}
```

JavaScript

```
(function($) {
    var getDiscountAmount(e) {
        var $input      = $(e.target);
        var product_id  = $input.data('product_id');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/ajax/product/' + product_id + '/discount',
            data: {
                quantity: $input.val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $input.prop('disabled', true);
            },
            success: function(discounts) {
                $input.prop('disabled', false);

                // Dunno what you want to do with list of discounts right there
                // It should be an array containing 1 object, but who knows
            }
        })
    }

    $(input[name="quantity"]).on('change', getDiscountAmount);
})(jQuery);
```

Hope it helps, didn't test the code so you may need to add some tweaks

Answer (score 0):

If you ever in a situation to share data from controller to JS, then I suggest using this package [JsTransformers](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer). It makes you do something like this

```
// in controller
public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => User::first(),
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return view('index');
}

// in view scripts
console.log(foo); // bar
console.log(user); // User Obj
console.log(age); // 29
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your query like this:

```
public function qtydisc($id, $qty){
      $price = DB::table('qty_discounts')
              ->where('product_id', $id)
              ->where($qty, '>=', 'min')
              ->where($qty, '<=', 'max')
              ->select('amount')
              ->first();
      return response()->json($price);
    }
```